# Visual Basic 6 Listview Annoyance

Tags: listview, vb6

I've populated a listview with names using Icon View.

The listview isn't full, and when you accidently catch a blank area of the listview it actually registers a click on the first item in the listview, which is triggering an event that hasn't actually happened.

Is there a way of catching a "non-click"

Thanks

John

[image]

Comment: Can you show us the properties that are set for the ListView, as well as your click handler code?

Comment: By blank area, do you mean a full list box item that has no assigned value, like a placeholder entry?

Comment: No, blank white space in the listview. An area that hasnt been populated. if you click in the white space, the click event is fired for the first item in the listview

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I seem to recall needing to use the HitTest method to validate the ListItem that was just clicked.  I captured the X/Y coords in the MouseDown then in the Click I validated that the click actually landed on a ListItem.

Comment: That's what I do. For bonus points, `Set ListView.SelectedItem = ListView.HitText(X, Y)`

Answer (score 2):

The *HitTest* method mentioned by tcarvin is sound. If you don't need the generic Click event though, it would be easier to opt for the *ItemClick* event instead. This should only fire when actually clicking on an item.